# Am having an issue with an npm package entry points

Tags: reactjs, npm, vite, next.js13

I have a React component library, and I'm having trouble importing it in a Next.js 13 app directory. My package.json file has the following configuration:

```json
  "type": "module",
  "main": "./dist/index.cjs",
  "module": "./dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",

  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import":{
         "default":"./dist/index.js",
            "types": "./dist/index.d.ts"
        },
      "require":{
          "default":"./dist/index.cjs",
            "types": "./dist/index.d.ts"
        }
   
    },
    "./accordion": {
      "import": "./dist/accordion/index.js",
      "require": "./dist/accordion/index.cjs",
      "types": "./dist/accordion/index.d.ts"
    },

    "./alert": {
      "import": "./dist/alert/index.js",
      "require": "./dist/alert/index.cjs",
      "types": "./dist/alert/index.d.ts"
    },

    "./alert-dialog": {
      "import": "./dist/alert-dialog/index.js",
      "require": "./dist/alert-dialog/index.cjs",
      "types": "./dist/alert-dialog/index.d.ts"
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ]
```

The library imports fine in Vite with:

```
import { Accordion,AccordionContent } from "my-ui-lib" 
or
import { Accordion,AccordionContent } from "my-ui-lib/accordion"
```

However, in the Next.js 13 app directory, it doesn't seem to be able to find the other entry points. By adding a "/" after the libname, it points me to the "dist" folder instead of the other entry points like in Vite. This is the workaround I'm using:

```
import { Accordion,AccordionContent } from "my-ui-lib" 
or
import { Accordion,AccordionContent } from "my-ui-lib/dist/accordion"
```

Could this issue be related to the fact that Vite is ESM by default, but Next.js is not? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using @my-ui-lib

Comment: @ArjisChakraborty :that doesn't work

Comment: Its not well supported in next without fiddling around a bit. See https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/39375.